# SQL Stored Procedure Creation

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Our client requires us the send all of the invoices for the month, each month.

The employees of our company upload invoices to a construction software package which uses SQL as its backend.

Is it possible to create a SQL stored procedure which copies all of the uploaded attachments linked to that client which were uploaded during that month?

Where would I start if I want to learn how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... things like stored procedures are highly vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: Once you've answered marc's question, mine is "copies all of the ..." - copies them *where*? Are they already in a table? Is the destination a table?